# CASE WHEN with query in THEN field

Tags: sql, case

Is it possible to have a `CASE WHEN` query where instead of `ELSE` being a 'text string' it returns a variable?

Example:

```sql
CASE WHEN (age NOT IN (SELECT age FROM PersonInfo) THEN 'field missing' ELSE (SELECT age FROM PersonInfo)
```

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code is going to return an error unless `PersonInfo` has zero or one rows.

Comment: When you use Case When you need to Maintain Same data types in both if And Else

Answer (score 1):

depending on the implementation you might have something like

```
SELECT IFNULL(age, 'age missing') 
FROM PersonalInfo
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(age, 'age missing')
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two option:

1. You can use subquery in else but only,  if subquery returns single value:

   ```sql
   CASE WHEN (age NOT IN (SELECT age FROM PersonInfo) THEN 'field 
   missing' ELSE (SELECT MAX(age) FROM PersonInfo) END
   ```
2. You can use join

   ```sql
   CASE WHEN (age NOT IN (SELECT age FROM PersonInfo) THEN 'field missing' ELSE pi.age END
   .....
   join PersonInfo on
   ```